# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around bMatix was corrupted

Tags: c++, gaussian

call tree:
populateMatrix(coeff,bMatrix, rows,cols);
solveMatrix(coeff, bMatrix, cols+1);

```
void solveMatrix(float aMatrix[][DEFCOLS+1],float bMatrix[DEFCOLS+1], size_t cols){
std::cout << "\nInside solveMatrix...: " << endl;
size_t N2 = cols;

std::cout << "\N2 is...: " << N2 << endl;
for(size_t p=0; p<N2; p++){
    //std::cout << "\nInside 1st for loop...: " << endl;
    // find pivot row and swap
    int max = p;
    for(size_t i=p+1; i<N2; i++){
        //std::cout << "\nInside 2nd for loop...: " << endl;
        if ( abs(aMatrix[i][p]) > abs(aMatrix[max][p]) ){
            max = i;
        }
    }

    //std::cout << "\nJust b4 all the swapping...: " << endl;

    float temp[] = { *aMatrix[p] };
    *aMatrix[p] = *aMatrix[max];

    *aMatrix[max] = *temp;

    float t = bMatrix[p];
    bMatrix[p] = bMatrix[max];


    bMatrix[max] = t;
    //std::cout << "\nDone all the swapping...: " << endl;

    if ( abs(aMatrix[p][p]) <= MINISCULE) {
        std::cout << "***** Error matrix value too small. Matrix is singular" << endl;
        return;
    }
    // Pivot /in A and b
    for(size_t i=p+1; i<N2; i++){
        float alpha = aMatrix[i][p] / aMatrix[p][p];

        bMatrix[i] = alpha * bMatrix[p];

        for(size_t j=p; j<N2; j++){
            aMatrix[i][j] -= alpha * aMatrix[p][j];
        }

    }

    std::cout << "\nAbout to do the back subst..: " << endl;
    // back subst.
     std::vector<float> outMatrix(N2, 0.0);
     int i =0;

    for(i=N2-1; i>=0; i--){
        float sum = 0.0;
        int j=0;
        for(j=i+1; j<N2; j++){
            sum += aMatrix[i][j] * outMatrix[j];
        }       
        if (aMatrix[i][i] > 0){
            outMatrix[i] =  ( bMatrix[i] - sum ) / aMatrix[i][i];
        }else {
            outMatrix[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    int g = 0;
    std::cout << "\nSolution: " << endl;
    for (;g < N2-1; g++) {
        cout << outMatrix[g] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
```

}  // end solveMatrix()

This an implementation of the Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting. The application
runs and gives results - incorrect reults, but then I get the error below after it returns.

As soon as it returns to the top of the call, I get the:
       Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around bMatrix was corrupted!!!

I have looked at this forever and cannot see why this is the case.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because the actual matrix size you are passing to solveMatrix() (i.e. cols+1) the is greater than the size of the actual array (coeff or bMatrix).

The easiest way to debug this is the following:

1. Completely clear the body of your function. Ensure that you won't get the error message any more.
2. Restore the first for() loop. See if this causes the error to appear.
3. ...
4. Repeat it until you find which exact part of your function causes the error. Then carefully look into it and ensure that you are not exceeding your array limits (i.e. if bMatrix is float[16], you're not writing bMatrix[16], [17] or more.